# I am using the epublib and I am trying to get the entire chapter of a book at a time

Tags: java, android, epublib

I am trying to get one chapter at a time of a book. I am using the Paul Seigmann library. However, I am not sure how to do it but I am able to get all the text from the book. Not sure where to go from there.

```
// find InputStream for book

InputStream epubInputStream = assetManager

            .open("the_planet_mappers.epub");

        // Load Book from inputStream

        mThePlanetMappersBookEpubLib = (new EpubReader()).readEpub(epubInputStream);

        Spine spine = new Spine(mThePlanetMappersBookEpubLib.getTableOfContents());
        for (SpineReference bookSection : spine.getSpineReferences()) {
            Resource res = bookSection.getResource();
            try {
                InputStream is = res.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
                String line;
                while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
                    line = Html.fromHtml(line).toString();
                    Log.i("Read it ", line);
                    mEntireBook.append(line);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you're still looking for an answer, but...
I'm working on it too right now. This is the code I have to retrieve the content of all the epub file:

```
public ArrayList<String> getBookContent(Book bi) {
    // GET THE CONTENTS OF ALL PAGES
    StringBuilder string = new StringBuilder();
    ArrayList<String> listOfPages = new ArrayList<>();
    Resource res;
    InputStream is;
    BufferedReader reader;
    String line;
    Spine spine = bi.getSpine();
    for (int i = 0; spine.size() > i; i++) {
        res = spine.getResource(i);
        try {
            is = res.getInputStream();
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                // FIRST PAGE LINE -> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
                if (line.contains("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\" standalone=\"no\"?>")) {
                    string.delete(0, string.length());
                }

                // ADD THAT LINE TO THE FINAL STRING REMOVING ALL THE HTML
                string.append(Html.fromHtml(formatLine(line)));

                // LAST PAGE LINE -> </html>
                if (line.contains("</html>")) {
                    listOfPages.add(string.toString());
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return listOfPages;
}

private String formatLine(String line) {
    if (line.contains("http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd")) {
        line = line.substring(line.indexOf(">") + 1, line.length());
    }

    // REMOVE STYLES AND COMMENTS IN HTML
    if ((line.contains("{") && line.contains("}"))
            || ((line.contains("/*")) && line.contains("*/"))
            || (line.contains("<!--") && line.contains("-->"))) {
        line = line.substring(line.length());
    }
    return line;
}
```

As you may have notice I need to improve the filter, but I have every chapter of that book in my ArrayList. Now I just need to call that ArrayList like `myList.get(0);` and is done.

To show the text in a proper way, I'm using the bluejamesbond:textjustify library (https://github.com/bluejamesbond/TextJustify-Android).
It is easy to use and powerful.

I hope it helps you, and if anybody finds a better way to filter that html, notice me, please.